# resolving values inside of a function in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code inside of a file called `Auth.js` .
    hasRole: function(){
            console.log(currentUser);
          return currentUser.role; //role is an array of objects but gives undefined
           }

I need to resolve the value of hasRole before redirecting anywhere just after login.

login looks like this:

```
 var role=[];

login: function(user, callback) {
        var cb = callback || angular.noop;
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post('/auth/local', {
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password
        }).
        success(function(data) {
          $cookieStore.put('token', data.token);
          currentUser = User.get();
          console.log(currentUser);//gives an unresolved promise (output is given after this piece of code.

           role = currentUser.role;  //gives undefined 
          deferred.resolve(data);    
          return cb();
        }).
        error(function(err) {
          this.logout();
          deferred.reject(err);
          return cb(err);
        }.bind(this));

        return deferred.promise;
      }}
```

and is called as follows:

```
 $scope.login = function(form) {
      $scope.submitted = true;

      if(form.$valid) {
        Auth.login({
          email: $scope.user.email,
          password: $scope.user.password
        })
        .then( function() {
          // Logged in, redirect to home
         var role = Auth.hasRole();
         console.log(role) //gives undefined.
        //Need to redirect on basis of value of role
        /*if(role.priority >= 1){
          $location.path('/admincontrol');

        }else{
          $location.path('/');

        }*/


        })
        .catch( function(err) {
          $scope.errors.other = err.message;
        });
      }
    };
```

How do I access currentUser.role here? I need to have its value in $scope.login just after login and just before redirecting so that I can redirect on basis of its value.

Edit: User service looks like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('createProjectApp')
  .factory('User', function ($resource) {
  //  return $resource('/api/users/:id/:controller', {
    return $resource('/api/customUsers/:id/:controller', {
      id: '@_id'
    },
    {
      changePassword: {
        method: 'PUT',
        params: {
          controller:'password'
        }
      },
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          id:'me'
        }
      }
      });
  });
```

`currentUser` when consoled in login looked like this:
 [image]

Comment: If `User.get()` returns a promise why do you expect `role` to be property of the promise? You already have usage of promises in your code, so you're supposed to understand that value will be resolved later and should be accessed in `.then`

Comment: @KirillSlatin: I am a new bie in angular and have started using angular fullstack by yeoman. so I was tryign to integrate pieces of code here and there. I am yet not very clear about the idea of promises.. It would be really helpful if you could please throw some light on it.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q light thrown. Alternatively; Google "angular promise"

Comment: That's kind but I actually meant with the case that I have since I had trouble understanding why currentUser.then was not a function.

Comment: Have you tried `currentUser.then`? If `currentUser` is a promise `then` SHOULD be a method on it.

Comment: I did. As Kirill Slatin has established the point that it was so since it was a resource call and not an http call that I had mistakenly assumed.

Comment: Ah, checked your log. `currentUser.$promise.then` is probably what you're after. The `$promise` property is the promise.

Comment: Oh, Is that? That's new and something I was completely unaware of. Let me try that as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User.get() is itself a function that returns a promise. You are going to have to wait on the promise fullfillment before continuing, as in

```
currentUser.then(function() {
  console.log(currentUser);
  role = currentUser.role;  //gives undefined 
  deferred.resolve(data);    
  return cb();
}
```

cb() itself is not needed since you are using promises - but you may have something special in mind.

Comment: It gives an error that says currentUser.then is not a function

Comment: @SimranKaur can share `User.get` implementation then? Why do you think that it returns a promise?

Comment: @KirillSlatin: I thought so because when I did console.log(currentUser) inside of login as mentioned above in the code, I got console output as given in the picture which I thought should suggest it's a promise?

Comment: Also, User.get is an http.get call to the api. so , I believe that should return a promise only?I have also updated the code with it.

Comment: @SimranKaur It's absolutely not obvious what the picture with log stands for. Looks like it's a result of `$resource` call. In my project I have different usage. Not attached `.then` but a callback provided to the method. It expect it to work `User.get(function(){...})` with the function that Paul wrote

Comment: Oh, That's right. I was blind enough to assume the api call to be an http call. It is actually a resource call.

Comment: @KirillSlatin: You saved me a lot of head banging.  Thank a ton for keeping up all this time.

Comment: It worked but help me with the last query,  how do I access roles in $scope.login ?All that I am getting in $scope.login is an object with token if I pass data and passing roles via deferred.resolve gives undefined. @KirillSlatin

Comment: @SimranKaur well it's hard to do without seeing code of `Auth.hasRole()`

Comment: Done. I needed to passback roles variable in return cb(roles); Thanks